# jQuery/Effects/ .delay() & .stop() functionality

Tags: jquery, effects

I'm trying to have my animation of my content `DIV` first fade out then stop at this fade it out stage and only queue the fade in so that `.dequeue()` can be called later once I have loaded content dynamically (probably through ajax).

```
$content.fadeTo(1000,0.0).delay(1000).stop().fadeTo(1000, 1)
```

I'm having two issues -

1. my fade out happens immediately and does not fade for 1 sec.
2. the `stop()` function doesn't stop anything the animation simply runs straight through.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

`$content.fadeTo(1000,0.0)` will fade out your div in 1 second (you could use `.fadeOut(1000)` if you want to).

Then, what `.delay()` does is daley the execution of subsecuent animations by the milliseconds you provided, so if you do

`$content.fadeOut(1000).delay(300).fadeIn();` It will fade out the div in a animation that lasts 1 second, wait 300 milliseconds and then fade the div back in.

So far so good, but what `.stop()` does is stopping the animation in the matched elements, so your `fadeTo` won't run, it doesnt queue things. Then when you do `.fadeTo(1000, 1)` (equivalent to `.fadeIn(1000)`) the div is already visible, so it does nothing.

I recommend you do:

```
$content.fadeOut(1000);

//Later in the code
$.ajax({
//...
success: function() {
     //code..
     $content.fadeIn(1000);
});
```

But if you want to queue the animation you could use [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [`dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/)